# "Click here to read this article" "Read More" Why these are bad for screen readers?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, accessibility, screen-readers

I use "read more" at the end of paragraph just for reminder for user same like P.T.O

Why it's problematic?

Comment: I've never heard of it being problematic... It's new to me.

Comment: @jitendra: can you elaborate, provide references where the "Read More"-like expressions are characterized as bad ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to understand that many screen reader users don't wait for the whole page to be read to them. They use keyboard shortcuts to navigate around the page. JAWS (arguably the most common of screen readers) has several very useful shortcut key combinations.  One in particular pulls up a list of all of the hyperlinks on any given page.  This way the user doesn't need to wait for the reader to get to the section of the page they're interested in before finding out what kind of links the page contains.  They can just use the shortcut and get a list of links all at once on demand.

It's when using the list of links shortcut that your "Read More" links are completely useless.  When viewing a huge list of all the links on the page, the user is simply read the text inside the  tags.  There is no context. The user has no idea what preceeds or follows the "Read More" text.  All they know is there's a link for them to "read more" about something.  This gets especially confusing when there is more than one link like this on the page. The user also does not generally listen to the URL, as that's pretty much worthless given all the insane query strings and the computerized voice struggles with reading URLs.

Does that help answer your question?

Comment: So basically context free link text is better?

Comment: Yep, you want the user to be able to figure out where the link takes them just by reading the text inside the <a> tag generaly.  I used to use the "Read More" or "Click Here" links, but when you actually spell it out the links do read alot better, even for sighted users.

Comment: yes it helped me +1. should i avoid multiple link with same link text on same page?

Comment: Yes - you want to avoid duplicate link text, and also make sure your link text can stand alone and be specific enough to describe the destination without any contextual help from the words around it :)

Comment: To add to your comment, if you must use "click here" or "read more" presentationally, consider adding a descriptive title attribute. For sure it's best practice to avoid this stuff if you can, but sometimes it just makes sense - like if you're rounding off a summary paragraph and are inviting the user to find out more.

Answer (score 2):

As a screen reader user and an occasional web designer (not to mention a web accessibility consultant), sometimes ambiguous links are unavoidable.  While it's not always convenient for a screen reader user to figure out the context of a particular ambiguous link, it's not that much of a burden to figure out one or two.  The problems come when pages are loaded with them.

When making this decision, you really need to consider if the extra wording in the link is too high a price to pay for the convenience to a screen reader user.  Usually, with a little thought, you can come up with a link text that is better for everyone.  However, just keep in mind that if you do have to use ambiguous link text, you won't "break" accessibility, just make it slightly less convenient for some.  On the spectrum of "must haves" to "nice to haves", this is well within the latter half, unless ambiguous links become the rule, rather than the exception.

Answer (score 1):

This [blog entry discusses the drawbacks of 'click here' links](http://friendlybit.com/other/click-here-to-read-this-article/).  Another drawback of 'click here' links is they do not help identify keywords to that might be associated with their target... think SEO.